# Restrict Countries and Cites in Flutter using session token

Tags: flutter, autocomplete, google-places-api

the following string of url correctly gives me locations within my country:

```
String autocompleteURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$placeName&key=$mapKey&sessiontoken=1234567890&components=country:my";`  //no Error
```

'my' gives all cities in Malaysia.
However, I want to restrict it to malacca within malaysia.I don't know how to use components for a particular city using session token.I searched the autocomplete documentation from google developers website.

After that, I changed the above code into:

```
String autocompleteURL= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=$placeName&types=establishment&location=2.25386,-102.27273&radius=500&key=$mapKey"; //error after change.
```

However, only this line gives me error after change.

Here, long and latitude values are the values for Malacca.
I am using my program in flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your output type from xml to json :

```
String autocompleteURL= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$placeName&types=establishment&location=2.25386,-102.27273&radius=500&key=$mapKey"; //error after change.
```

Comment: Yes, working after changing it to json...but the problem is now I am getting addresses from certain cities in USA . I need Malacca. Is there any problem with longitude OR latitude values.